# TypeError: users.hasPermission is not a function

Tags: node.js, command, discord, discord.js

Trying to make a tempmute command on discord and im getting the following error: `TypeError: users.hasPermission is not a function`

I want to make it so that you cannot use this command on the user who has MANAGE_MESSAGES perms

heres the code Im using, I have been trying to fix this for hours now, any help woks
Thank you :)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports = {
    category: 'Moderation',
    name: 'tempmute',
    commands: ['tempmute', 'tm', 'mute'],
    description: 'tempmutes the user for a specified time',
    requiredPermissions: [
        'MANAGE_MESSAGES'
    ],
    callback: (message, args, member, users, tag, id) => {

        if(users.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.reply('You cannot mute that person!');

        if (message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Muted")) {

            message.channel.send(`**${message.mentions.members.first()} is already muted`)
            
            }

        var member = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]));
        if(!member) return message.reply(':nomark: Please Provide a Member to TempMute.')

        let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ")
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");

        if (!role) return message.reply(":nomark: Couldn't find the 'Muted' role.")

        let time = args[1];
        if (!time){
            return message.reply(":nomark: You didnt specify a time!");
        }
        
        if(!reason) {
            return message.reply("Please provide a reason")
        }

        member.roles.add(role.id);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        embed.setDescription(`<:yesmark:791577741002539029> **${message.mentions.members.first()} has been muted for \`${reason}\` for \`${time}\`**`)
        member.send(`You are muted in **${message.guild.name}** for \`${reason}\` for \`${time}\``)
        message.channel.send(embed);

        setTimeout( function () {
            member.roles.remove(role.id);
        }, ms(time));
    
},
permissions: 'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

> I want to make it so that you cannot use this command on the user who has MANAGE_MESSAGES perms

Ok, so you want to prevent users from muting people who have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` perm. Then what is the `users` variable? Is it a list of all users with that perm? I'm assuming so, since the variable is a plural `users` and not `user`. So how would the *list* of users have a `.hasPermission()` method (only a single user has that function property)? And assuming that `users` is a list of all users with the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` perm, what is the point in checking if the users in that list have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` perm? You already know that all of the users in `users` have that perm, because `users` is supposed to be the list of users with that perm.

So let's look at what you want to do again, and build a solution from there: "so you want to prevent users from muting people who have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` perm". So let's dissect that further. The user specifies a person they want to mute. You don't want them to be able to mute people who have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` perm. So all you need to do is check if the person they specified has that perm. Checking `users` is not going to work; you need to get the person they specified in `args[0]` and check if *that* person has the perm.

Though this solves the problem you are currently experiencing, your code still has some other errors in it which I will also address below.

First of all, when you are checking whether or not the specified person is already muted, you're doing: `message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Muted")`. That doesn't check if the specified person is already muted, it checks if the user that sent the command is muted (and obviously they aren't, otherwise they wouldn't be sending the command).

Second, some of your code isn't really in a logical order. You're defining `reason`, then checking if the muted role exists, then checking if the time exists, and only after all of that are you checking if `reason` exists. This isn't technically an error, but it makes it more difficult for people reading the code (and potentially yourself) to follow along. I will be reordering some of this in the below solution.

Third, you aren't adding `.catch()` statements to your role addition, role removal, and DM-sending lines. If an error occurs when trying to mute someone, you need to catch that error and notify the user that an error occurred. Otherwise, you risk your bot going offline or restarting (due to the error) at a time when your users need your bot to mute someone, and preventing them from muting that person.

**The Solution**

These are the changes you need to make to your callback in order to fix this. Also note that this assumes that `users` is a list (array or `Collection`) of users who have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` perm. If that is not the case, I apologize for misunderstanding and this solution may not work for you. But given the information you've presented in your question, I am assuming that you do not need to use the `users` variable at all for what you are trying to achieve.

```
callback: (message, args) => {

    //Get member by mention or ID
    var member = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]));
    if(!member)
        return message.reply(':nomark: Please Provide a Member to TempMute.');

    //Prevent muting users with MANAGE_MESSAGES perms
    if(member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
        return message.reply('You cannot mute that person!');

    if (member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Muted"))
        return message.channel.send(`**${member} is already muted`);

    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
    if (!role) return message.reply(":nomark: Couldn't find the 'Muted' role.")

    //Get time
    let time = args[1];
    if (!time) return message.reply(":nomark: You didnt specify a time!");
    
    //Get reason
    let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ")
    if(!reason) return message.reply("Please provide a reason");

    //Send embed
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`<:yesmark:791577741002539029> **${message.mentions.members.first()} has been muted for \`${reason}\` for \`${time}\`**`);
    message.channel.send(embed);

    //Tell member they are muted
    member.send(`You are muted in **${message.guild.name}** for \`${reason}\` for \`${time}\``)
    .catch(err => console.log(`Cannot DM user: ${member.user.tag}.`));

    //Mute member
    member.roles.add(role.id)
    .catch(err => message.channel.send(`Could not mute the user: ${member.user.tag}.\nError:\n\`\`\`\n${err.stack}\n\`\`\``));

    //Unmute member
    setTimeout( function () {
        member.roles.remove(role.id)
        .catch(err => message.channel.send(`Could not unmute the user: ${member.user.tag}.\nError:\n\`\`\`\n${err.stack}\n\`\`\``));
    }, ms(time));

}
```

I've added comments to several parts of the code to make it a bit more readable, as well.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot it works perfectly fine, 
 if (member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Muted")) { <-- just had to remove this bracket here because it made the rest of the code unreachable, other than that everything worked fine, once again thank you for going out of your way to help me, you even corrected my other mistakes :), I cant thank you enough.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for pointing out that bracket, I've updated the answer to fix that :)